# Volume Controls

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got a serious of games which in turn load off a main main swf.

I have mute and unmute buttons on the main menu and the same buttons in each game.

When I unload/load a game I want the volume to stay as it is so they player doesn't have to keep turning the volume off.

AudioOff is the button shown when the volume is off and AudioOn is the button shown when the volume is on.

Any ideas of how to do this?

EDIT:

The code I've got now keeps the volume on or off through the games but the buttons aren't showing up correct with this code..

```
if (SoundVolume.volume == 1)
{
    AudioOn.visible = false;
    AudioOff.visible = true;
}

if (SoundVolume.volume == 0)
{
    AudioOff.visible = false;
    AudioOn.visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Flash Cookies to store the user's sound preference:
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/

If the saved cookie preference is to mute all sound, you can use the following code:

```
var s:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
s.volume=0;
SoundMixer.soundTransform=s;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to change/load/unload games?

If there is a main class running behind all of it, you can have a variable or two with the volume and on/off, and each game can grab the values when they load. Whenever one of the games changes the value, they should pass that back to the main class.

If it is loading a separate page for each one, you'll need to do something with cookies. You can use a SharedObject in each game and the menu to hold the volume and on/off variables. Actually, this would work for both situations. SharedObject tutorial [here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/).